# How can I get the duration of call and save it to a variable in my dialplan?

Tags: asterisk

```
exten => 3333,10,hangup

exten => 3333,11,Set(x=${CDR(billsec)})

exten => 3333,12,noop(${x})
```

Comment: i try to take the call bill duration from CDR billsec field.it is not working

Answer (score 7):

The call dies with the "HangUp()" command, and call processing stops.  As a result, priorities 11 and 12 are not reached.
However, we can "prolong" the life of the call past the hangup condition with a special extension, "h".  Please try changing your code as follows:

```
exten => 3333,10,HangUp()

exten => h,1,Set(x=${CDR(billsec)})
 same => n,NoOp(${x})
```

... and let me know if that works for you.

Recommended reading: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Handling+Special+Extensions

Comment: it is not working     -- Executing [h@from-internal:1] Hangup("SIP/11pitzi-00000010", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (from-internal, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/11pitzi-00000010'
  == Spawn extension (from-internal, 3333, 8) exited non-zero on 'SIP/11pitzi-00000010'
    -- Executing [h@from-internal:1] Hangup("SIP/11pitzi-00000010", "") in new stack
  == Spawn extension (from-internal, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/11pitzi-00000010'

Comment: MichelV69 , sorry i made a mistake and run the h with 3333.your Answer is working for me !! great !  Thanks !!!!!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out.  Do me the favor of "accepting" my answer, please.  Thanks very much and I'm always happy to help or consult.